# VBA - automatically run when any workbook is opened

Tags: vba, excel

I want a Sub in my PERSONAL.XLAM file to run every time any workbook is opened. The following works, but only when opening a workbook when no other workbook is open.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Hello."
End Sub
```

How can I make this work upon opening additional workbooks?

Comment: you could write a code in the Auto_Open sub of each workbook in question maybe ? I am not sure I fully understand your question... and to make sure you don't try to open it more than once you can verify if it is open or not before doing so

Comment: I want a macro to automatically run on every single workbook that is opened as soon as it is opened. There are going to be thousands of different workbooks, so I can't add them to each workbook.

Comment: Do you open those workbooks via a Main workbook ?

Comment: No. I open them manually.

Comment: You can't:( Personal.xlam (or any other file) can't see when other files are opened. It works for you for the first opening only because that time personal.xlam is opened too. The only way is to place a code in all of your workbooks.

Comment: Then you'll need to write a macro to add code to the "thousands of different workbooks"

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940204/vba-automatically-run-when-any-workbook-is-opened#comment74913409_43940204) from Masoud, [this is a great article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx). You can find  all the detail there, but simply, this is all you need:

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "New Workbook: " & Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Place the code into your *ThisWorkbook* module.